# Windows 10 and Grub not working properly

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, mbr

I recently decided to test Winodows 10 on my HP dv6 laptop with Ubuntu 14 installed. I was able to get Windows up and running without any problems but getting Ubuntu and Windows to boot properly has been a real hassle. When installing Windows the Grub was obviosly removed I reninstalled it with BootRepair. Now I could run Ubuntu but the entry for Windows 10 in Grub says Windows Recovery loader for the partition that Windows 10 occupies and when it is selected and booted into it only gets as far as the Windows logo and then stops and gets stuck. To fix this I did a fixmbr and sure enough windows is working fine. Then I reinstalled Grub and I still have the same Windows 10 Recovery entry that does not boot into windows. I am back were I started, only able to boot windows by fixing the mbr and Ubuntu by boot repair. What is causing this and What should I do to get them both working on grub?

```
    sudo update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-51-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-51-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-49-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-49-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-48-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-48-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-46-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-46-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-45-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-44-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-44-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows Recovery Environment (loader) on /dev/sda2
done
```

Partitions sda2 is windows

image of grub: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzUgn.jpg
image of partions: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyn6s.png